# Need to understand a portion of jquery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

here i am posting a jquery code which is working but few lines are not clear to me . 
[js fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/p4e4psg4/5/).

full code

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" action="WebForm1.aspx" id="ctl00">
    <input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Fly DIV" id="Button1" class="toggleUPSContainer" />
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
#UPSContainer{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background:red;
    height:0;
    width:0;
}
```

**javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $els = [];
    var data = {
        "UPSContainer": {
            "height" : 100,
            "width" : 100
        },
        "isAnimating" : false
    };
    $els.window = $(window);
    $els.form = $('#ctl00');
    $els.toggleUPSButtons = $('.toggleUPSContainer');

    function addUPSOverlay(){
        $els.form.append('<div id="UPSContainer"></div>');
        $els.UPSContainer = $('#UPSContainer');
    }

    function getNewWindowCorner(){
        data.windowWidth = parseInt($els.window.width());
        data.windowHeight = parseInt($els.window.height());
        if($els.UPSContainer.is(':hidden')){
            $els.UPSContainer.css({
                top: data.windowHeight + 'px',
                left: data.windowWidth + 'px'
            });
        }else{
            $els.UPSContainer.css({
                left: ((data.windowWidth - data.UPSContainer.width) / 2) + 'px',
                top: ((data.windowHeight - data.UPSContainer.height) / 2) + 'px'
            });
        }
    }

    function containerOpenComplete(){
        // do what you want here when opening complete
    }

    function containerCloseComplete(){
        // do what you want here when closing complete
    }

    function toggleUPSOverlay(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(!data.isAnimating){
            if($els.UPSContainer.is(':hidden')){ // currently closed so open
                $els.UPSContainer.show();
                $els.UPSContainer.animate({
                        left: ((data.windowWidth - data.UPSContainer.width) / 2) + 'px',
                        top: ((data.windowHeight - data.UPSContainer.height) / 2) + 'px',
                        height: data.UPSContainer.height + 'px', 
                        width: data.UPSContainer.width + 'px'
                }, 200, function(){
                    containerOpenComplete();
                });
            }else{ // currently open so close
                $els.UPSContainer.animate({
                        left: data.windowWidth + 'px',
                        top: data.windowHeight + 'px',
                        height: 0 + 'px', 
                        width: 0 + 'px'
                    }, 200,
                    function () {
                        $els.UPSContainer.hide();
                        containerCloseComplete();
                    });
            }
        }
    }

    function attachEvents(){
        $els.window.on('resize', getNewWindowCorner);
        $els.toggleUPSButtons.on('click', toggleUPSOverlay);
    }

    function initialize(){
        addUPSOverlay();
        getNewWindowCorner();
        attachEvents();
    }

    initialize();
});
```

this function's code is not clear

```
function getNewWindowCorner(){
        data.windowWidth = parseInt($els.window.width());
        data.windowHeight = parseInt($els.window.height());
    }
```

just see **windowWidth & windowHeight potion**

```
var data = {
        "UPSContainer": {
            "height" : 100,
            "width" : 100
        },
        "isAnimating" : false
    };
```

data has been declared as object and it has property like `height, width & isAnimating etc` but how we can add two new property called `windowWidth & windowHeight` to data object ??

just seeing the below code it seems that we can add any property to any object with any name at runtime in javascript and here we are storing value to `windowWidth & windowHeight` property.

```
data.windowWidth = parseInt($els.window.width());
data.windowHeight = parseInt($els.window.height());
```

so just see my whole code and tell me from where these two property comes **windowWidth & windowHeight ?** thanks

### EDIT 1

Need bit more help. what it is called in js `var $els = [];`? is it array or object? what is the difference between var `$els = []; and var els = {};` ? if this is array `var $els = [];` then how one can push anything into array like this way `$els.window = $(window); or $els.body = $('body');`. please help me understand the usage with small sample. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For normal ones you can add them on the fly. They don't have to be declared from the start with the object. If they are they'll only be overwritten.

So you could either add everything you want from the start...

```
var data = {
  "UPSContainer": {
    "height": 100,
    "width": 100
  },
  "isAnimating": false
};
```

.. or create it as you go

```js
var data = {};

data.UPSContainer = {};

data.UPSContainer.height = 100;
data.UPSContainer.width = 100;

data.isAnimating = false;

data.windowWidth = parseInt($els.window.width());
data.windowHeight = parseInt($els.window.height());
```

Comment: thanks for nice reply. please see my edit 1 because i need few more help.

Answer (score 1):

> it seems that we can add any property to any object with any name at runtime in javascript

Yes. You can. You just assign the new values.

> where these two property comes windowWidth & windowHeight

From the code you are asking about. The assignment creates those properties.

Answer (score 1):

In ECMAscript3 and ECMAScript5 , any property can be added to any object,
either by dot assignment, or through an array type notation.

```
data.windowWidth = parseInt($els.window.width());
```

or

```
data['windowWidth'] = parseInt($els.window.width());
```

create 'windowWidth' property for the data object.
In ECMA5 , this behaviour can be altered by following function:

```
Object.preventExtensions( obj )
```

and you can use `Object.isExtensible( obj )` to check the current behaviour of that object.
If you try adding property to such an object for which extensions have been prevented, you would get an error in strict mode.

For your second question, in javascript array is also an object having properties , date is also an object , hence you can add properties to the array.

Comment: thanks for nice reply. please see my edit 1 because i need few more help.